# Making a bone hides using a switch?

Tags: rigging

Is it possible to make certain bone disappears/switch looks, using a switch or some sort? I had this assumption after seeing auto rig pro's rig ,where if i switch fk to ik , vice versa, i see the bone changes shape. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple ways to make an FK/IK Switch in Blender. Here's the blend file of
the method I use :

[image]

And here are the steps I go through to make it :

- Create a separate bone, visible at all times
- Add a custom property on this bone

  - Type : Integer
  - Name : "FK/IK Switch"
  - Default : 0
  - Min : 0
  - Max : 1
- Right-click on the custom property > Copy as New Driver
- In the outliner, paste the driver onto the visibility switch of the
  desired bones :

[image]

- Change the expression on the FK bones to `1 - custom_property`
- Done !